# Tkinter: Changing tab colors removes button borders in unrelated dialogs

Tags: python, tabs, dialog, tkinter, themes

In Python 3.4 with Tkinter, the following code to change tab colors in my Notebook makes it so the outlines of buttons and stuff in my seemingly unrelated open file dialog are non-existent.

```
style = Style();
style.theme_create("tabcolor", settings={"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"background": self.tbgcolor, "foreground": self.tfgcolor }, "map": {"background": [("selected", self.atbgcolor)], "foreground": [("selected", self.atfgcolor)]}}});
style.theme_use("tabcolor");
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Here's an image of the dialog with the problem. Notice there are no outlines on the buttons:

[image]

Edit: This also causes checkboxes in Text widgets to appear unchecked even when they're checked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this problem.

First, the solution is to configure styles and stuff instead of making a theme. If you make a theme, it's more error-prone. I think the theme was applying the Notebook style to all widgets, or else it was only adding the specified styles while leaving everything else blank (not leaving them with the defaults). I'm not 100% sure on the why, to be honest, but I know the solution. Use this instead of making and using a theme:

(self.d is a dictionary that contains the colors and stuff, and need not be part of your code.)

```
Style().configure("TNotebook", background=self.d["tcolor"]); #This line isn't technically part of the answer, but people seeing this will likely want to know this, too (it changes the color of the tab bar portion without tabs on it).
Style().map("TNotebook.Tab", background=[("selected", self.d["atbgcolor"])], foreground=[("selected", self.d["atfgcolor"])]);
Style().configure("TNotebook.Tab", background=self.d["tbgcolor"], foreground=self.d["tfgcolor"]);
```

Essentially, this is the same code in the theme, but it's not affecting everything with it (just the stuff you want it to). I figured this answer out by examining the documentation via Python's help function. I saw the map method (which Style uses instead of a dictionary for that), and attempted translating. It worked (this time).